# How do I insert multiple products when quantity is unknown?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert, inventory

I'm trying to build an inventory system to keep track of some products in my company.  It isn't an online store or anything, just a way for me to keep track of what products are in shipping, in an electrician's truck stock, or in the office.

I've already built pages to show current inventory levels of what's in limbo (shipping to a tech or the office), what techs have, and what is here in the office.  I can also see what stock each tech has also.  Now I just need a way to assign products to one of these locations when they are drop shipped by our supplier.

The Insert Inventory page has a form that displays fields for every item we keep track of, and a quantity box next to it.  It also has a select box for choosing what to assign the inventory to and where it is intended to go next.  (For example: Shipping -> Tech)

> **So, it might look like this:**
>
> ---
>
> **Choose Location Type** Select List
>
> **Choose Going To** Select List
>
> 12/2 Indoor Wire (Read Only)............Quantity Field
>
> 10/2 Outdoor Cable (Read Only)..............Quantity Field
>
> Submit Button
>
> ---

There is actually going to be about 60 products on this page.  Ideally, if they put 10 in the 12/2 wire field, it'll insert into the database 10 records that have:

> id(*AI*), product_id, location_type_id, location_going_id, date

And if I put 3 on 10/2 quantity then it will insert 3 records of that also.

Here is the code for my form.  Right now there's not much else.

```
      <form action="insert2.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
  <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text" value="10/2 Outdoor Cable" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text" value="12/2 Indoor Wire" readonly id="product_name[]"></td>
      <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" size="5" id="qty[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
              </p>
</form>
```

And then I have it going to the second page to insert it into the database:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product_name']); $i++) {
$product = $_POST['product_name'][$i];
for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['qty'][$i]; $j++) {

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name)
VALUES ('$product')");
}

}
?>
```

When I get to the second page, it shows: *string(16) "12/2 Indoor Wire"* and it inserted 1 of the 10/2 outdoor cable items.  I put 3 for outdoor and 4 for indoor products.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_POST)`, before the for loop?

Comment: It says:  array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "10/2 Outdoor Cable" [1]=> string(16) "12/2 Indoor Wire" }

Comment: Seems that the `qty[]` is not being posted. Is the above HTML your exact code? This seems strange.

Comment: Yes it is, except for the html, head tags. I put var_dump for qty underneath the other one and it says this:
array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "10/2 Outdoor Cable" [1]=> string(16) "12/2 Indoor Wire" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you had actually added `var_dump($_POST)` as per my suggestion - not some specific posted value. Alright. And what happens now? Does it insert only one product?

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know I could just use ($_POST).  That'll be handy. I put 2 qty for product 1.  4 qty for product 2.  It inserted one product 1.  Though the var_dump shows everything accordingly.

Comment: I'm curious: Can you please update your code with the actual code? Just remove the part that involves your connection credentials.

Comment: Ok, I took out the connection details.

Comment: But you didn't update the rest of the code - I didn't mean that. I meant **add all your php code**, and just replace the connection details.

Comment: That is all there is.  I have one file with just a form that goes to another page and it just has that little snippit of code above.  Both of them are a test to see if I can get it to work.  Not full blown pages.

Comment: Please replace the `mysql_query` with `print "INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name)
VALUES ('$product')"` and let us know

Comment: It says: INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name) VALUES ('10/2 Outdoor Cable')INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name) VALUES ('10/2 Outdoor Cable')INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name) VALUES ('10/2 Outdoor Cable')INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name) VALUES ('12/2 Indoor Wire')INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name) VALUES ('12/2 Indoor Wire').  Why did it work with print but not the other?

Comment: This chat is growing too large, and I believe this question has been answered as to *how to run a query multiple times*. Maybe you would prefer to debug your code a little, and if you can't find anything on Google, you can start a new question. You should do some research, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your HTML to

```
<input name="product_name[]" .. />
```

And then you will be able to manipulate `$_POST["product_name"]` as an array, containing all posted values.

You need to do the above for both the `product_name` input, and the `qty` input, so that you can do any necessary actions.

If you want to insert multiple records based on your quantity, your code must look something like:

```
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product_name']); $i++) {
    $product = $_POST['product_name'][$i];
    for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['qty'][$i]; $j++) {
      // insert $product
    }
  }
?>
```

If your quantity is just another column in the product table, then your code should look like:

```
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product_name']); $i++) {
    $product = $_POST['product_name'][$i];
    $query = 'INSERT INTO .. (`product_name`, `qty`) '.
             ' VALUES ("'.$product.'", "'.$_POST['qty'][$i].'")';
  }
?>
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example. You need to check and escape values in real code.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.  But it only inserted each product on the form once.  How do I make it know that if someone puts a number in the quantity field for each product to insert that many particular products?

Comment: That isn't working for me.  It inserts a single record : (
Right now, I just have the first product field and qty field.

`<input name="product_name[]" type="text" value="xti"><input name="qty[]" type="text" size="5">`

And then on page 2 I have:

`<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['product_name']); $i++) {
    $product = $_POST['product_name'][$i];
    for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['qty'][$i]; $j++) {
      // insert $product
    
    /* verify data, do sql escaping */


    

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inv_inventory (product_name)
VALUES ('$product')");
 
 }
}
?>`

Comment: Do you want to add to your question, the updates you made to the code, and a `var_dump` of your `$_POST` ?

Comment: Doing so now.  Sorry, I wasn't sure what to do.